# SignInManager could not be found (without using outdated packages)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity

I don't wanna use any outdated packages like `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin` or `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`
I'm using dotnet 7 and all packages and runtimes are updated to the latest version
Here is my code

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace Hamrin.Infrastructure.Identity;

public class IdentityService : IIdentityService
{
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole<Guid>> _roleManager;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager; //error here
}
```

And my csproj:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\Hamrin.Application\Hamrin.Application.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.4" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And I'm getting this error

```
 The type or namespace name 'SignInManager<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly refe
rence?)
```

Comment: Where did you get this error?

Comment: @QingGuo what do you mean? I can not build project because of this error

Comment: Which line of code get this error?

Comment: private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

Comment: What's your project temple ?

Comment: Because my .project file has `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`, your  project is `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`. I am confused.

Comment: Because it's a class library and yours is Web project

Comment: I can see you have a Identity package in your class library which has`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`.  So what's Hamrin.Infrastructure.Identity ? A  class library ? Is it have a  Identity package  ?

Answer (score 0):

add the following code to Program.cs and test it out

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(options 
=> {                             options.Stores.ProtectPersonalData = false;
```

options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric =false;     options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 0;     options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;               options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;     options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = true;           options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;               options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = false;               options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;   }).AddDefaultTokenProviders()
.AddSignInManager<AppSignInManager()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

Comment: No it didn’t help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this has been resolved but thought I'd add my share.

Using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI fixed this for me as they have the latest packaging that isn't deprecated that can be used with .NET7.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Identity will be changed in .net 8 for good